# Creating a PDF viewer using iTextSharp

Tags: pdf, itext

I am trying to create a PDF viewer using the iTextSharp library, but there doesn't seem to be any documentation anywhere about how I can accomplish this. I don't need to create a PDF file, just display one and give users the option to save the file or export it to a CSV file.

Can somebody please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Right direction looks like not inventing the wheel. If you would consider a third party tool I'd suggest you to take a look at this [blog post](http://blog.apitron.com/2013/12/free-pdf-viewer-control-for-windows-forms.html) which demos a winform viewer control with integrated text search. Implementing a viewer is a HARD task and it's better to save time and use ready-to-use solution unless you need anything really unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iText is not a PDF viewer (nor iTextSharp) for that matter, but it could be used to examine a PDF document. See for instance [iText RUPS](http://itextpdf.com/product/itext_rups). iText RUPS is a tool that allows you to look under the hood of a PDF, more specifically at the PDF objects stored in a PDF as well as at the content streams.

This would be the first step towards writing a PDF viewer. However, iTextSharp doesn't *interpret* the content stream of a page, nor the resources that belong to that page (such as image streams, glyph descriptions, etc). If that's what you want to build, you need to consult ISO-32000-1. Note that it will probably take several man years to create a decent viewer.

As for the requirement to export a PDF document to a CSV, this may be possible if your original PDF is a Tagged PDF, but it will be impossible for the majority of PDF documents, including documents that consist of scanned images and documents with no machine-recognizable structure.

Please understand that this is a general answer. A more specific answer can not be given since your question is too broad for StackOverflow. All the answers you need can be found by using iText RUPS and reading ISO-32000-1 (there's a copy of ISO-32000-1 available on Adobe's web site).